# NodeFilter is undefined error when using IE Compatibility mode with Kendo UI SPA application

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, single-page-application, ie-compatibility-mode, kendo-ui-mvc

I am building a Kendo UI application which is working perfectly fine in IE11. But when I add the site to be displayed in compatibility mode in IE11 i am getting an error "'NodeFilter' is undefined'. It raises this error while rendering the layout. see below code.

```
var appRouter = new kendo.Router({
  init: function () {
    layout.render("#application");
  }
});
```

Error is raised in kendo.web.min.js where it tries to remove white spaces (I guess by the name). This is the line of code that is failing.

```
var t=document.createNodeIterator(n,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,function(t){...}
```

**EDIT:**
<s>I am not sure where the NodeFilter is defined. I cannot find it in kendo.web.js or kendo.core.js. Please help</s> 
Just learned that NodeFilter is a property for window object. window.NodeFilter is null when compatibility mode is enabled in IE11. But Telerik demo SPA site works fine under these settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question answered in Telerik Forums. Unfortunately Kendo UI do not support IE Compatibility mode.

You can see the thread on Telerik forums [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/nodefilter-is-undefined-error-when-using-ie-compatibility-mode-with-kendo-ui-spa-application)